# Do frame fields (tetrads) satisfy orthonormality vector field condition if orthogonal?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Referencing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_fields_in_general_relativity#Relationship_with_metric_tensor.2C_in_a_coordinate_basis :

Suppose we start directly from $g^{\mu \nu}= e^{\mu}_{\ a} e^{\nu}_{\ b} \eta^{ab} \,$ (eq 1), where $g$ of course refers to metric tensor, and $e$ refers to tetrad, with $\nu$ representing Lorentz metric. Assuming some coordinate system, if tetrads are set to satisfy eq 1 and tetrads satisfy orthogonality condition, then wouldn't tetrads also satisfy orthonormality conditions? Or is there any other condition needed to make tetrads to be orthonormal vector fields instead of just orthogonal vector fields?

Comment: What orthonormality condition do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g,e,\eta$ denote the corresponding matrices. Equation is $$ g^{-1}=e\eta^{-1}e^T. $$

Invert everything here: $$ g=(e^T)^{-1}\eta e^{-1}. $$ Now express $\eta$: $$ e^Tge=\eta\Leftrightarrow e^\mu_ag_{\mu\nu}e^\nu_b=\eta_{ab}. $$ There's your ortonormality condition.